# Extract exact string from json object

Tags: javascript, json

JSON string looks like this

```
{
    "en": {
        "home": "Home"
    },
    "de": {
        "home": "Startseite"
    }
}
```

I would like to the get the value of "home" for "en" only

I can parse the string from local storage into JSON object like this

```
var value = $.parseJSON(window.localStorage.getItem("language_strings"));
```

But i dont know how to get the string from value for the key "home" when the language is "en"

Comment: it's just object properties, don't you know how to do that?

Comment: I wouldnt ask if i knew the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After parse you will get object having property `en`.
Just read it like this:

```
var homeVal = value.en.home;
```

Comment: Thanks. That gets the correct value nice and simple.  If i wanted to use variables there is it possible.  For example value.language.key - where language and key are variables that represent en and home

Comment: If you want to use variables, you use array notation `value[language][key]`.

Comment: @patrickcoote That is right, it is better for architecture to have language values separated from implementation, because that way you can simply add another language.